# css ставим стили для последних букв

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Можно ли с помощью `CSS` для последних 4 букв в `<p>` установить свой стиль?

Comment: на чистом css нельзя, на сколько мне известно, но я бы призвал @Qwertiy, у него всегда в запасе есть пара трюков.

Comment: вот тут есть несколько решений для последнего слова https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268386/css-for-changing-color-of-last-word-in-h1

Comment: @secret_coder, можно, если вы обернете последние 4 буквы тегом и укажете ему стиль ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без js тут точно не обойтись.

Пример:

```js
$("p").lettering();
```

```css
p span:nth-last-child(1),
p span:nth-last-child(2),
p span:nth-last-child(3),
p span:nth-last-child(4){
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lettering.js/0.7.0/jquery.lettering.min.js"></script>
  
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, dolorem quas? Beatae officiis repellendus quam dignissimos tempora laborum voluptatibus. Iste</p>
 
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, dolorem quas?</p>
```

Используется плагин [lettring.js](http://letteringjs.com/)